# Npm vulnerabilities can't be fixed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, linux, npm

I started learning react and created my first app by running:

> 'npx create-react-app my-app'

After the app was built I got a warning in the terminal that says:

> 22 vulnerabilities (9 moderate, 13 high)

I tried to fix it by running:

> 'npm audit fix'

But it returned this:

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Found: type-fest@0.21.3
> npm ERR! node_modules/type-fest
> npm ERR!   type-fest@"^0.21.3" from ansi-escapes@4.3.2
> npm ERR!   node_modules/ansi-escapes
> npm ERR!     ansi-escapes@"^4.2.1" from @jest/core@26.6.3
> npm ERR!     node_modules/@jest/core
> npm ERR!       @jest/core@"^26.6.0" from jest@26.6.0
> npm ERR!       node_modules/jest
> npm ERR!         peer jest@"^26.0.0" from jest-watch-typeahead@0.6.1
> npm ERR!         node_modules/jest-watch-typeahead
> npm ERR!         1 more (react-scripts)
> npm ERR!       1 more (jest-cli)
> npm ERR!     ansi-escapes@"^4.3.1" from jest-watch-typeahead@0.6.1
> npm ERR!     node_modules/jest-watch-typeahead
> npm ERR!       jest-watch-typeahead@"0.6.1" from react-scripts@4.0.3
> npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
> npm ERR!         react-scripts@"4.0.3" from the root project
> npm ERR!     2 more (jest-watcher, terminal-link)
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peerOptional type-fest@"^0.13.1" from @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.4.3
> npm ERR! node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
> npm ERR!   @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@"0.4.3" from react-scripts@4.0.3
> npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
> npm ERR!     react-scripts@"4.0.3" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! See /home/azizdragon/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /home/azizdragon/.npm/_logs/2021-06-23T03_09_31_663Z-debug.log

I tried deleting the package-lock.json file and node_modules folder and run:

> npm install

But it resulted in the same vulnerabilities, here is the report when I run "npm audit":

> browserslist  4.0.0 - 4.16.4
> Severity: moderate
> Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1747
> fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
> Will install react-scripts@1.1.5, which is a breaking change
> node_modules/react-dev-utils/node_modules/browserslist
> react-dev-utils  >=6.0.0-next.03604a46
> Depends on vulnerable versions of browserslist
> node_modules/react-dev-utils
> react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
> Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
> Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
> Depends on vulnerable versions of mini-css-extract-plugin
> Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
> Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
> node_modules/react-scripts
>
> css-what  <5.0.1 Severity: high Denial of Service -
> https://npmjs.com/advisories/1754 fix available via `npm audit fix --force` Will install react-scripts@1.1.5, which is a breaking change node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-what   css-select  <=3.1.2
> Depends on vulnerable versions of css-what
> node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
> svgo  >=1.0.0
> Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
> node_modules/svgo
> @svgr/plugin-svgo  *
> Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
> node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
> @svgr/webpack  >=4.0.0
> Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
> node_modules/@svgr/webpack
> react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
> Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
> Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
> Depends on vulnerable versions of mini-css-extract-plugin
> Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
> Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
> node_modules/react-scripts
> postcss-svgo  >=4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9
> Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
> node_modules/postcss-svgo
> cssnano-preset-default  *
> Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-normalize-url
> Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-svgo
> node_modules/cssnano-preset-default
> cssnano  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.1.11
> Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano-preset-default
> node_modules/cssnano
> optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin  3.2.1 || 5.0.0 - 5.0.4 || 5.0.6
> Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano
> node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
>
> glob-parent  <5.1.2 Severity: moderate Regular expression denial of
> service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1751 fix available via `npm audit fix --force` Will install react-scripts@1.1.5, which is a
> breaking change
> node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/glob-parent
> node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/glob-parent   chokidar
> 1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8   Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent   node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar
> node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar
> watchpack-chokidar2  *
> Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
> node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2
> watchpack  1.7.2 - 1.7.5
> Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack-chokidar2
> node_modules/watchpack
> webpack  4.44.0 - 4.46.0
> Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack
> node_modules/webpack
> webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 3.11.2
> Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
> node_modules/webpack-dev-server
> @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin  0.3.1 - 0.5.0-beta.4
> Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
> node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
> react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
> Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
> Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
> Depends on vulnerable versions of mini-css-extract-plugin
> Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
> Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
> node_modules/react-scripts
>
> normalize-url  <=4.5.0 || 5.0.0 - 5.3.0 || 6.0.0 Severity: high
> Regular Expression Denial of Service -
> https://npmjs.com/advisories/1755 fix available via `npm audit fix --force` Will install react-scripts@1.1.5, which is a breaking change node_modules/normalize-url
> node_modules/postcss-normalize-url/node_modules/normalize-url
> mini-css-extract-plugin  0.6.0 - 1.0.0   Depends on vulnerable
> versions of normalize-url   node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin
> react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
> Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
> Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
> Depends on vulnerable versions of mini-css-extract-plugin
> Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
> Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
> node_modules/react-scripts   postcss-normalize-url  <=4.0.1   Depends on vulnerable versions of normalize-url
> node_modules/postcss-normalize-url
> cssnano-preset-default  *
> Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-normalize-url
> Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-svgo
> node_modules/cssnano-preset-default
> cssnano  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.1.11
> Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano-preset-default
> node_modules/cssnano
> optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin  3.2.1 || 5.0.0 - 5.0.4 || 5.0.6
> Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano
> node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
>
> 22 vulnerabilities (9 moderate, 13 high)
>
> To address issues that do not require attention, run:   npm audit fix
>
> To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:   npm audit
> fix --force

Should I use npm audit fix --force?
If it helps, I run Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit
Node version: v16.0.0
NPM version: 7.18.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run npm audit fix a few more times, then I think the moderate number should decrease or the warnings will decrease each time and actually work again. I once solved it that way.

Comment: got the same problem. being new to node ecosystem, I am getting worried now - if basic, standard script creates an app with so many critical vulnerabilities, what does it tell about the maturity of the tools...

Comment: Oddly enough I happened to have just read [this blog post by Dan Abramov](https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/) on this issue. The gist is that many of these vulnerabilities probably can't affect an application created with Create React App in practice because many of these dependencies are used only in development.

Comment: @alexakarpov Read https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/ for more details, but it's not a reflection on the maturity of the tools, but of how the implementation of `npm audit` is problematic. These issues might be a problem if you were using them in the context of a Node.js application where they were deployed to production, but in the context of Create React App they aren't. You only really need to worry about anything flagged by `npm audit --production`.

Answer (score 4):

As Matthew Daly has mentioned in the comments following this blog post [npm audit: Broken by Design](https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/) by Dan Abramov, ***most of or maybe all warnings are related to development dependencies, so they will not affect your production build***, and you don't need to worry about fixing them at all.

It doesn't mean that development dependencies' vulnerabilities are harmless in every situation, every package and every version.

In my experience, most of the time there is no way to resolve all issues using `npm audit` and almost always using `npm audit --force` will make the situation even worse and break your app.

So I ignore these warnings when I'm installing the latest version of a popular, highly maintained package like create-react-app.

Surely Maintainers of libraries like CRA are aware of these warnings and would fix them immediately if they were serious.

Another way to make sure that these warning are harmless is to check the [reported issues of the create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues) or any other library and see what the responses had been.

I highly recommend you reading the mentioned article, [npm audit: Broken by Design](https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/).

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure CRA is no longer maintained. Vite is a good alternative if the application is purely front end.

https://medium.com/@dawid.niegrebecki/create-react-app-is-dead-what-to-use-instead-fcdd46b70295